# Can I combine !ATTLIST features in one line of a DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am just learning to write XML and associated DTD's, and I'm wondering if I can combine certain things in one line of an !ATTLIST.

eg:

I have an element `weight`, and I want to have `(kg|lb)` as options, but set `"kg"` as the default.  None of these are essential, so the status is `#IMPLIED`, but I also want to have a default weight of "1".

Can I legally put all this in one line:

```
<!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST weight unit CDATA "1" (kg|lb) "kg" #IMPLIED>
```

Or can I do it this way:

```
<!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST weight unit CDATA>
<!ATTLIST weight unit "1" #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST weight unit (kg|lb)>
<!ATTLIST weight unit "kg" #IMPLIED>
```

I suspect there are problems with both, and I am a little confused as to how I combine these features (or if I even can) - so I would really appreciate a little guidance on doing this properly.

Comment: Shouldn't `"1"` be the default value for `weight` element instead of `unit` attribute?

Comment: Yes, it probably should... that would make more sense, thanks - although I can't see how to set a default value for an element, just an attribute.  Is it done the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have got it working by doing the following, although it might not be the 'accepted practice' way:

```
<!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST weight qty  CDATA "1">
<!ATTLIST weight unit CDATA (kg|lb) "kg">
```

I had to break the value out into its own attribute (which makes sense now I think about it), and remove the #IMPLIED, since I read somewhere that by setting a default value, its implied anyway.

Hopefully this will help someone else (assuming its the right way to do it)

Cheers

Comment: Does your browser render `"]>"` character in your document? How did you fixed that?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember the details - this was something I was doing at uni over 2 years ago.  From memory I wasn't rendering the document in a browser - it was just an XML file for storing data for a Java program I had written as part of an assignment.